# How to submit exception to Sentry so that I can find it in issues?

Tags: flutter, sentry

I followed [readme](https://pub.dev/packages/sentry) to configure Sentry.
After configuring I created a test that reports an exception. The test passed, but I do not see the exception in Sentry's list of issues.

What can be wrong?

Reporter:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:sentry/sentry.dart';

class ReporterModule {
  final SentryClient _sentry;
  final bool outputToConsole;

  ReporterModule(String sentryDsn, {this.outputToConsole = true})
      : _sentry = sentryDsn == null ? null : SentryClient(dsn: sentryDsn);

  void reportError(FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    print('dsn: ${_sentry.dsnUri}');
    print('client: $_sentry');
    try {
      _sentry?.captureException(
        exception: details.exception,
        stackTrace: details.stack,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Sending report to sentry.io failed: $e');
    } finally {
      if (outputToConsole) FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
    }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
  test('Error reporting completes.', () {
    var reporter = ReporterModule(prodConfig.sentryDsn, outputToConsole: false);
    reporter.reportError(FlutterErrorDetails(
        exception: "test exception", stack: StackTrace.current));
  });
```

Test output:

```
dsn: https://a7c87a8f13894461b8d0af95284e5bd2@o484150.ingest.sentry.io/5536982
client: SentryClient("https://o484150.ingest.sentry.io/api/5536982/store/")
```

The DSN is copied from here:
[image]

Comment: hey @polina-c your DSN looks wrong, be sure to copy the right value from the Sentry settings page, docs: https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/dsn-explainer/

Comment: i think my DSN looks exactly as you described. It is just client.toString() look differently. I updated the question so you can see it.

Comment: a DSN looks like this: {PROTOCOL}://{PUBLIC_KEY}:{SECRET_KEY}@{HOST}{PATH}/{PROJECT_ID}

your example ends with a '/store/' which is not part of the DSN, the /store path is added by the SDK automatically.

Comment: I did not get your point. In the test output at the end of my post I see that dsn ends with '5536982', and 'client.toString()' ends with '/store/', that is align with the rules you explained.